# How to get ip Ranges in C#?

Tags: c#, ip, range

I am a newbie .I  write a program to get IP Range in C# 4.0 it works well for the small ranges but when I go for ranges like class A IP address, my program takes a lot of time .Need some help .Here is my code (its not a good approach ). Any suggestion to write in better way.?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ipSplitt
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] z = new string[4];
            int t = 0;
            string ip = "3.0.0.0";

            string[] Ip = ip.Split(new char[] { '.' });

            foreach (string m in Ip)
            {
                z[t] = m;
                t++;
            } 

            int a1, b1, c1, d1 = 0;

            a1 = Convert.ToInt32(z[0]);
            b1 = Convert.ToInt32(z[1]);
            c1 = Convert.ToInt32(z[2]);
            d1 = Convert.ToInt32(z[3]);

            string[] v = new string[4];
            string ip2 = "3.255.255.255";
            int l = 0;
            string[] Ip2 = ip2.Split(new char[] { '.' });

            foreach (string m in Ip2)
            {
                v[l] = m;
                l++;
            } 

            int a2, b2, c2, d2 = 0;

            a2 = Convert.ToInt32(v[0]);
            b2 = Convert.ToInt32(v[1]);
            c2 = Convert.ToInt32(v[2]);
            d2 = Convert.ToInt32(v[3]);

            while (d2 >= d1 || c2 > c1 || b2 > b1 || a2 > a1)
            {
                if (d1 > 255)
                {
                    d1 = 1;
                    c1++;
                }

                if (c1 > 255)
                {
                    c1 = 1;
                    b1++;
                }

                if (b1 > 255)
                {
                    b1 = 1;
                    a1++;
                }

                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("import.txt",true))
                    writer.WriteLine(a1 + "." + b1 + "." + c1 + "." + d1);

                d1++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> but when I go for ranges like class A IP address, my program takes a lot of time

Because you're opening and closing a file handle 255^3 times. Put the `using(Streamwriter ...)` block around the outer while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [IPAddress class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.aspx) in the .NET framework, and the [static Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse.aspx) function.

Comment: That is not what OP is doing. He's not parsing them, but printing.

Comment: I might have understood his question wrong then. PS. +1 for your answer. Just noticed it after I wrote my answer. But when I wanted to edit you already answered it.

Answer (score 1):

Much time go to this

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("import.txt",true))
                writer.WriteLine(a1 + "." + b1 + "." + c1 + "." + d1);
```

So you should to do this

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Int32.MaxValue);
        sb.Append(a1.ToString() + "." + b1.ToString() + "." + c1.ToString() + "." + d1.ToString() + "\n");
```

and after all just call

```
        File.WriteAllLines("import.txt", sb.ToString().Split('\n'));
```

Comment: Throws out of memory exception on my system

Comment: Before put downvote try to do this StringBuilder(Int32, Int32)

Comment: This time throws the exception on initialization of the StringBuilder and previous one uses more than 500M of memory befor throwing the exception. I think this is a little problematic

Comment: In addition; first version of your code throws the exception on String.Split operation not at the StringBuilding. My platform Windows XP x64 4 GB RAM

Comment: I read that in some version of VS you should to do Int32.MaxValue/8

Comment: Int32.MaxValue == 4GB RAM )))

Comment: I have win7 and 8GB thats why i can start, but even Int32.MaxValue/8 will be enough (so please delete your downvote)

Comment: Problem isn't StringBuilder, problem is your approach isn't good. Because you allocate a huge memory with StringBuilder then create an String array with String.Split this means you double up the used memory. And this is a small single run application it shouldn't use more than 1GB memory. May be it works on your system but as i said this isn't a good approach

Comment: @accfews Realy thank you for all your comments I'll take them into account

Answer (score 1):

StringBuilder solution throws out of memory exception on my system, so you should simply add

```
 StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("import.txt");
```

on top of your function then replace

```
 using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("import.txt",true))
            writer.WriteLine(a1 + "." + b1 + "." + c1 + "." + d1);
```

with

```
writer.WriteLine(a1 + "." + b1 + "." + c1 + "." + d1);
```

and add

```
writer.Close();
```

to the bottom. Completes in 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is straightforward and here are good answers already. But... What is an IP address? It is a four-byte integer, right? So why not to parse the range limits as int32, and then print numbers between to output stream with use of mask to get decimal representation:

```
127.0.0.1 = 01111111 00000000 00000000 00000001
a = ip & 0xFF000000
b = ip & 0x00FF0000 
c = ip & 0x0000FF00
d = ip & 0x000000FF
```

But still don't forget to initialize a stream out of loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the file each time so it gets flushed for every IP. Put the using statement around the while block.

Answer (score 0):

The statement that writes to the file import.txt is the main culprit which causes the loop to slow down.  I think you should replace StreamWriter code with  `ips.AppendLine(a1 + "." + b1 + "." + c1 + "." + d1);`  Here, ips is a StringBuilder object.
Outside the loop, I wrote following code:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("import.txt", false))
char[]  arr ;

arr = new char[ips.Length]  ;
ips.CopyTo(0, arr, 0, ips.Length) ;

writer.Write(arr);
writer.Dispose()
```

Here I do not dump the string from StringBuilder to import.txt.  But I copy to char[] and then I dump.  I have observed that this is lot faster.  I hope this helps !!